# Animate one at a time with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to use `ngRepeat` to load an image and play it's associated tone, then move the image from the center of the circle to a specific position on a circle, and proceed with the doing the same thing with the next image. I got the images to display and move one by one using `ng-enter-stagger`, however the images have different positions so when I change it to to use a different class for each repetition, `ng-enter-stagger` does not work.

How can I go about loading one image, moving it to the proper position, hiding the image, then proceeding with the next image?

I have created a plunkr but the animation does not work in it https://plnkr.co/edit/DddST6JsemsCKKf3mQ6N?p=preview. 
An example of what I want to do is the Learn the sounds part of this (http://www.absolutepitchstudy.com/animalgame/) click either Start Control or Start Animal Game

The data looks like this:

```
"ImageTones":[{"CPosition":"deg60","Image":{"ImageFileName":"Alligator.png","ImageId":1},"Tone":{"ToneFileName":"C3.mp4","ToneId":1}},
{"CPosition":"deg0","Image":{"ImageFileName":"Cow.png","ImageId":4},"Tone":{"ToneFileName":"B5.mp4","ToneId":2}},
{"CPosition":"deg270","Image":{"ImageFileName":"Bird.png","ImageId":3},"Tone":{"ToneFileName":"E3.mp4","ToneId":3}}]
```

**Html page:**

```
<div class="circle-container">
     <div ng-repeat="it in model.imageTones" class="it.CPosition">
         <img ng-src="../Content/Game/Animals/{{it.Image.ImageFileName}}"/>
         <!--Audio tag goes here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS (I may be able to fix this to not have as many classes, just am unsure how)**

```
.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 38em;
    height: 38em;
    padding: 2.8em;
    /*2.8em = 2em*1.4 (2em = half the width of a link with img, 1.4 = sqrt(2))*/
    border: dashed 1px;
    border-radius: 80%;
    margin: -5.25em auto 0;
}

.circle-container div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    margin: -2em;        
}

.circle-container div.ng-enter {
    transition: 5s linear all;
    opacity: 0;        
}
.circle-container div.ng-enter-stagger {
  /* this will have a 100ms delay between each successive leave animation */
  transition-delay: 5.0s;

  /* As of 1.4.4, this must always be set: it signals ngAnimate
    to not accidentally inherit a delay property from another CSS class */
  transition-duration: 0s;
}

.circle-container div.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  /* standard transition styles */
  opacity:1;
}


.deg0.ng-enter-active {
    transform: translate(19em);
}


.deg30.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(30deg) translate(19em) rotate(-30deg);
}


.deg60.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translate(19em) rotate(-60deg);
}

.deg90.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(19em) rotate(-90deg);
    transition: transform 5s;
}

.deg120.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(120deg) translate(19em) rotate(-120deg);
}

.deg150.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(150deg) translate(19em) rotate(-150deg);
}

.deg180.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(19em) rotate(-180deg);
}

.deg210.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(210deg) translate(19em) rotate(-210deg);
}

.deg240.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(240deg) translate(19em) rotate(-240deg);
}

.deg270.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translate(19em) rotate(-270deg);
}

.deg300.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(300deg) translate(19em) rotate(-300deg);
}

.deg330.ng-enter-active {
    transform: rotate(330deg) translate(19em) rotate(-330deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of errors to look at 1st, To get a value of a class from an angular item, it's ng-class you should be looking for:

```
  <div ng-repeat="it in model.imageTones" ng-class="it.CPosition" ng-if="!it.hidden" >
    <img ng-src="http://www.absolutepitchstudy.com/animalgame/content/images/{{it.Image.ImageFileName}}" />

  </div>
```

Then in you style sheet there seems to be something wrong with the CSS, so I removed a class that wasn't being used:

```
.deg60{
    transform: rotate(60deg) translate(19em) rotate(-60deg);
}
```

Although to hide stuff you may want that back.
The updated plunk with the work so far is at:

[plunky](https://plnkr.co/edit/ULfQNV)

Now it's being rendered in the right place, you can use $timeout, ng-click or someother method to alter the class definition in your model. The position of the graphic should automatically update.

What method were you going to use?

Comment: Thanks for updating the plunk, the image should start in the center and then move towards it's proper position. I was planning on using $timeout and seeing if there is a way to specify when the tone is done playing then start the next image

Comment: @EitanK I've updated the example, to show a very basic movement after 1000 seconds. Obviously you need to add some user controls and decide what the game should really do. Hope that helps. Note also I've added programmically whether something is hidden or not. Allowing only one creature on at any one time. I also moved the ng-class to the containing div.

Comment: I got a basic movement to work (unfortunately my plunkr does not reflect it). However they are all moving from the center to the spot all at once. The only way I can get the movement to work one at a time is to use ng-enter-stagger but that does not work if they have different CSS classes.

Comment: @EitanK I added one more update, I think ng-style may be more suitable here, please check it out. You can put (in finite control over your element with this method. Plus it means you don't have to keep replacing classes/adding classes.